# using array.shift() affects wrong variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm assuming I'm doing something really dumb here. I basically have an array that I'm passing into a function. I want to remove an element of that array and do a bunch of stuff to it, and then iterate through the rest of the array as long as there are still members in that array. When the array is empty, I want to loop back and run through the original array again.

However, I'm running into a weird issue when using array.shift(). It seems to be affecting the wrong variable if that even makes sense.

Abstract example as follows:

```
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  function goThroughArray(array){
      var untouchedArray = array
      console.log('untouched array before is ' + untouchedArray)

      var insideArray = untouchedArray
      console.log('inside array is ' + insideArray)

      var removedNumber = insideArray.shift()
      console.log('removed number: ' + removedNumber + ' from  insideArray')

      console.log('inside array after is ' + insideArray)
      console.log('untouched array after is ' + untouchedArray)
  }

goThroughArray(originalArray)
```

The console log output yields:

```
untouched array before is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
inside array is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
removed number: 1 from insideArray
inside array after is 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
untouched array after is 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

This is without any looping going on. Can someone explain why doing the shift() on the insideArray ALSO affects the untouchedArray??

I would expect that the insideArray would lose it's first member which is stored as "removedNumber" but why is the untouchedArray also losing it's first member?

**EDIT**

```
    function addOne(number){
            console.log('number in is: '+number)
            var original = number;
            var modified = original
            console.log('original before is ' + original)
            console.log('modified before is ' + modified)
            modified++
            console.log('original after  is ' + original)
            console.log('modified after  is ' + modified)

        }

        addOne(1)
```

Yields:

```
 number in is: 1
 original before is 1
 modified before is 1
 original after  is 1
 modified after  is 2
```

**NEW EDIT**

Although this question is super old, I figured I would update with a much cleaner method to solve this question:

```
 JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

will create a copy of the object.

Comment: Because your "insideArray" is actually a reference on "untouchedArray". You will have to copy the elements to get a true copy of the variable. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another)

Comment: see edited post. The result of that function is that the "original" variable never changes. It remains as "1". Why is that?

Comment: I thiiink, that primitive data types (numbers, strings) are copied but objects are referenced. At least it's how Java handles it.

Comment: You might want to look into using the reduce() method of Arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Javascript objects are never copied. If you write

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var b = a;
```

both `a` and `b` are just pointers to the same array object. Thus for example executing `a.push(99)` you will see the new element when dumping `b` too.

It **seems** that copies are done with immutable types like numbers or strings:

```
var a = 14;
var b = a;
b = b + 3;
console.log(a); // still 14
```

but this happens because the `+` operator returns a new number object and `b` is bound to this new one instead of the old one.

If you need to make a copy you must do that explicitly. For arrays the solution is calling the `slice` method passing no parameters.

```
var b = a.slice(); // Makes a new independent copy of the array
```

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I never knew how javascript worked with objects and memory. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

javascript is pass by value language. read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language) for more inforamtion or google it.

In this case, you should clone your array.

try this

```
let insideArray = untouchedArray.slice();
```

Comment: That does seem to work. Although I used "var" instead of "let". I had a weird error when I tried "let". Why does this not apply to the second function listed? The "getOne" function?

Comment: @RossvanZyl, if you use external source for javascript you should use this attribute for work in best case.
``<script src="main.js" type='application/javascript;version=1.8'></script>``

Comment: [JS does not have "pass by reference"](http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com.es/2013/11/javascript-does-not-have-pass-by.html)

Comment: Use var. Let isn't as supported as var, and will give you issues on FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

In JS, assignments are done by value:

```
var a = 1,
    b = a; // 1 (by value)
a = 2;
b; // 1 (not modified)
```

However, in the case of objects, that value is a reference in memory. That means that if you modify a property of the object, you will see the change in all variables:

```
var obj1 = {},
    obj2 = obj1;

obj1.foo = 'bar';
obj2.foo; // 'bar' (the change is reflected in the other variable)

obj1 = {}; // However, if you replace the entire object, the change
           // won't be reflected because assignments are done by value
obj1.foo; // undefined
obj2.foo; // 'bar'
```