# Cannot edit classList while looping through it

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

I have an element like this :

```
<span class="util bg-color-yellow tooltip bg-color-red"></span>
```

And I wanted to remove all class starting with "bg-color-", so I would simply loop thru all the class, then remove the matched ones :

```
var element = document.getElement......;

var elementClasses = element.classList;


for( var i = 0, l = elementClasses.length; i < l; i++ )
{
    var className = elementClasses[i];

    // console.log(i);
    // console.log(name);

    if( className.startsWith('bg-color-') )
    {
        element.classList.remove(className);
    }

    console.log('elementClasses contain :');
    console.log(elementClasses);
}
```

When it matches the 'bg-color-' class, it successfully remove the class name, but it also edit the variable `elementClasses` as if it's a reference to `element.classList`, even if it's a variable ( copy ) of it.

1st loop :

```
elementClasses = [ util bg-color-yellow tooltip bg-color-red ]
```

2nd loop :

```
elementClasses = [ util bg-color-yellow tooltip bg-color-red ]
```

3nd loop :

```
elementClasses = [ util tooltip bg-color-red ]
```

**There goes the problem**! `elementClasses` is modified on the same time as the `elemnt.classList` is modified!

- How is that possible ?
- Is effectively `elementClasses` a sort of reference of `element.classList` ?
- Did `elementClasses` recreated it self each time `element.classList` is modified ?

.

**Thank you very much! :)**

Comment: So loop backward

Comment: Instead of using a `for (/*...*/) {/*...*/}` loop, use `[...elementClasses].forEach(/*...*/)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this post this explains the answer of how javascript copies variables when you use '=' sign

[Copy a variable's value into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another)

Comment: wow, thanks I never heard of javascript reference before. It sure would be very helpful for the future!

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you've identified what's causing the problem. Now for the solution:

```
// ES6
[...elementClasses].forEach((className, i) => {
// OR ES5
Array.prototype.slice.call(elementClasses).forEach(function (className, i) {

    // console.log(i);
    // console.log(className);

    if( className.startsWith('bg-color-') )
    {
        element.classList.remove(className);
    }

    console.log('elementClasses contain :');
    console.log(elementClasses);
});
```

Using either of these methods, the `classList` is shallow-copied to ensure that you are not skipping entries when an array is modified.

To answer your other question, `elementClasses` in your original code is indeed a reference to `element.classList`, which is why both of them were modified when one of them was.

In my ES6 suggestion, `[...elementClasses]` uses the spread operator to make a shallow copy into a native `Array`, while the ES5 method calls `slice()` on the original `element.classList` to make a shallow copy of it.

Now for a demo:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('span');
var elementClasses = element.classList;

// ES6
// [...elementClasses].forEach((className, i) => {
// OR ES5
Array.prototype.slice.call(elementClasses).forEach(function (className, i) {

    console.log(i);
    console.log(className);

    if( className.startsWith('bg-color-') )
    {
        element.classList.remove(className);
    }

    console.log('elementClasses contain :');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(elementClasses));
});
```

```html
<span class="util bg-color-yellow tooltip bg-color-red"></span>
```

Comment: Thank-you for this tip!

Answer (score 0):

In your implementation `elementClass` is not actually a copy of `element.classList`. It is a reference to the same object. To copy the object consider using `.slice()`.

See this question:
[Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)