# JavaScript, deleting property from a copy of original Object, actually affecting the original Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Say I have an array of objects

```
var result = [{
    "sss": "sssssss",
    "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
    "www": "1212121",
    "Group": "Mango"
}, {
    "sss": "sssssss",
    "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
    "www": "1212121",
    "Group": "Mango"
}]
```

I want a final result like :

```
var result ={
   "Mango" : [
        {
            "sss": "sssssss",
            "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
            "www": "1212121"
        }, {
            "sss": "sssssss",
            "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
            "www": "1212121"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I did this

```
var obj = [];

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++ ){
    if(obj[result[i].Group] && obj[result[i].Group].constructor === Array ){

    }else{
        obj[result[i].Group] = [];
        // ################### PROBLEM ==========
        var x = result[i];
        delete x.Group;
        console.log(result[i]);
        // ################### ==================
        obj[result[i].Group].push(result[i]); // error: result[i].Group is undefined 
    }
}
```

the code `"delete x.Group"` should delete property `"Group"` from var `"x"`
            But actually the `console.log(result[i]);` shows 
            the property `"Group"` is deleted from 
            `result[i]` (which is original). HOW?

Looks like variable `x` is reference to the original `result[i]`, this am not sure.
How the deleting a property from the copy of the object is affecting the original. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: You answered it yourself `Looks like variable x is reference to the original result[i]`

Comment: See my answer to this question for some details about @WaleedIqbal's comment: [Copy a variable's value into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another/29096222)

Comment: If you want to copy a JavaScript array instead of just getting a new reference to it, you can use the `.slice()` method, e.g. `var x = result[i].slice();` Note that this does a "shallow" copy; it makes a new array, but it doesn't make new copies of any nested objects, only references to them. Other options such as a "deep" copy are mentioned in the answer I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a `hash` structure. Also. use `delete` operator in order to delete one object' property.

```js
var result = [{
    "sss": "sssssss",
    "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
    "www": "1212121",
    "Group": "Mango"
}, {
    "sss": "sssssss",
    "yyy": "ssdsdsds",
    "www": "1212121",
    "Group": "Mango"
}]

var groupByField = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    delete x[key];
    return rv;
  }, {});
};
console.log(groupByField(result, 'Group'));
```

However,

> How the deleting a property from the copy of the object is affecting
>   the original ?

You have to apply **deep clone** for that object.