# Why doesn't my function change value of variable?

Tags: javascript, html, function, return, var

I have a problem when I try to change value of my variable.

```
var id = null;
async function getUser() {
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    let passs = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    let res = await eel.login(user, passs)();

    let text = res[0];

    let id_res = res[1];

    if (text == 'Вы успешно авторизовались!') {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else if (text == 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль') {
        alert(text);
    }

    var copy = $.extend( {}, id );
    copy = id_res; // that's my problematic part

    alert(id); // allerting updated variable
}
```

Then, when I try to use **"id"** variable, it still returns **"null"**.

```
async function createTask() {
    let task = document.getElementById('need_task').value;

    let result = await eel.create_task(copy, task);
    alert(copy); // got error, that copy is undefined
}
```

In addition, in my html, I added **document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', getUser);** and **"document.getElementById('but').addEventListener('click', createTask);"** to activate my functions.

As you can see, I use python eel library. So I guess, that my mistake is with that eel.
I will appreciate any of your hepl!

Comment: `var id` declares a *new* variable called `id` which shadows the declaration `var id` from outside.

Comment: can you do a consol.log(res[1])

Comment: But when I run "alert(id)" in my first function, value has changed

Comment: Moaud louhichi, yes, when I do consol.log(res[1]), I get right value.

Comment: try removing keyword 'var' from this line 'var id = id_res;'

Comment: Still got nothing

Comment: put `id = id_res` instead of `var id = id_res;`  in `getUser()` because `var id` will create new variable in memory so, `id` in `getUser()` global `id`are different that's why it's remains `null` in the `createTask()`.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help, but it did't work.

Comment: equals operator `=` creates a reference to res[1] but after `getUser()` is done `res` is destroyed. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another

Answer (score 1):

You should read this to understand copy in javascript: [Copy a variable's value into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829099/copy-a-variables-value-into-another)

```
var id = null;
async function getUser() {
    let user = document.getElementById('user').value;
    let passs = document.getElementById('pass').value;

    let res = await eel.login(user, passs)();

    let text = res[0];

    let id_res = res[1];

    if (text == 'Вы успешно авторизовались!') {
        window.location.href = 'index.html';
    } else if (text == 'Неправильное имя пользователя или пароль') {
        alert(text);
    }

    id = id_res; // remove var

    alert(id); // will alert updated value.
}
```

no need to change 2nd function now

Comment: I had read thisinformation, but I guess that didn't get it. I edited my code after reading, please look at it.